# how to create an account except the way of using cleos?

Tags: python, c++

guys!I am a beginner of eos.
As it is said on the title, i want to create accounts by the way other than using cleos.

I have traversed the doc of eos, but not seen the interface to create an account directly.
I have tried the way by using RPC API abi_json_to_bin,sending json data like:

> {
>     "code": "eosio",
>     "action": "newaccount",
>     "args": {
>       "creator": "eosio",
>       "name": "acctest",
>       "owner": {
>         "threshold": 1,
>         "keys": [
>           {
>             "key": "EOS4ufZoTw95yHJS6Cyz3h4w5a2W4cyYpMYRnd7gbFZuCfPxUFS6r",
>             "weight": 1
>           }
>         ],
>         "accounts": [],
>         "waits": []
>       },
>       "active": {
>         "threshold": 1,
>         "keys": [
>           {
>             "key": "EOS4ufZoTw95yHJS6Cyz3h4w5a2W4cyYpMYRnd7gbFZuCfPxUFS6r",
>             "weight": 1
>           }
>         ],
>         "accounts": [],
>         "waits": []
>       }
>     }
>   }

and got response like:

> {"code":500,"message":"Internal Service Error","error":{"code":4,"name":"parse_error_exception","what":"Parse Error","details":[{"message":"Expected '\"' but read 'E'","file":"json.cpp","line_number":100,"method":"stringFromStream"},{"message":"while parsing token ''","file":"json.cpp","line_number":123,"method":"stringFromStream"},{"message":"Error parsing object","file":"json.cpp","line_number":218,"method":"objectFromStream"},{"message":"Attempting to parse array []","file":"json.cpp","line_number":249,"method":"arrayFromStream"},{"message":"Error parsing object","file":"json.cpp","line_number":218,"method":"objectFromStream"},{"message":"Error parsing object","file":"json.cpp","line_number":218,"method":"objectFromStream"},{"message":"Error parsing object","file":"json.cpp","line_number":218,"method":"objectFromStream"},{"message":"","file":"json.cpp","line_number":460,"method":"from_string"}]}}

have spent a couple of days on this single question,hope to solve it as soon as possible.
thanks!

Comment: not good at english, plz forgive me~.~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is an error in your request.

**abi_json_to_bin** is needed to convert action data from json format to binary hex format, which will be used for the data field in **push_transaction**.

Try [this](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#push_transaction) and check the Note section below.

Comment: json format wrong.